# Perl variables scoped within a sub

Tags: perl, scope

How would I scope to this variable depending on a conditional of papertype?

I have tried it several ways and I am getting errors and I am befuddled.

```
sub paperdisplay_getPaperLink {
    my ( $self, $args ) = @_;
    my $paper    = $args->{paper};
    my $linktext = $args->{linktext};
    my $session  = $args->{session};

    my $query    = $self->request;
    my $password = $query->param('password');

    if ( $paper->{Type} eq 'Break' ) {
        my $url = $something;
    } else {
        my $url = $somethingelse;
    }

    my $link = qq(<a title="$linktext" target="other" href="$url">$linktext</a>);

    return $link;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to declare it in the block you want to use it in. If you declare it inside the `if` or `else` block, it'll only exist there. The variable would be destroyed when the block ends.

```
my $url;
if ($paper->{Type} eq 'Break') {
    $url = $something
} else {
    $url = $somethingelse
}
# $url still exists down here
```

Comment: Or you could do `my $url = $somethingelse;` outside the loop and change it if that condition is true.

Comment: @Sobrique Why contradict yourself and make the computer do extra work?

Comment: Because the computer doesn't deserve to have an easy time of it. It's been naughty and must be punished. 

But honestly, it depends on scenario - if _usually_ it'll be one state, but _occasionally_ it will be different, setting the 'default state' and switching it on hitting the exception I feel improves code clarity.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Conditional Operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator) to initialize a variable without the need for an if block:

```
my $url = $paper->{Type} eq 'Break'
    ? $something
    : $somethingelse;
```